# Laravel - Join two tables advaced search

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Sorry for last question, I did not express my doubt in the best way
Hey, i have to know the properties that have more than N number of rooms.

House model

```
public function imovel(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Imovel::class); //property
}
```

Apartment model

```
public function imovel(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Imovel::class); //property
}
```

Property model

```
public function atributos(){
        //se for moradia/  House
        if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 1) {
            return $this->hasOne(Moradia::class);
        }
        //se for apartamento/  Apartment
        else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 2) {            
            return $this->hasOne(Apartamento::class);
        }
        //se for loja / SHOP
        else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 3) {
            return $this->hasOne(Loja::class);
        }
        //se for armazem
        else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 4) {
            return $this->hasOne(Armazem::class);
        }
        //se for terreno para construção
        else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 5) {
            return $this->hasOne(TerrenoConstrucao::class);
        }
        // se for terreno para outros fins
        else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 6) {
            return $this->hasOne(TerrenoOutrosFins::class);
        }
    }
```

and im using scopes to search:

This scope im searching all houses that have more N number of bedrooms, but i have to search apartments too

```
public function scopeProcuraNrQuartosMoradia($query,$nrQuartos){
    if ($nrQuartos != 0) $query ->join('moradias','imoveis.id', '=', 'moradias.imovel_id')
                                ->where( 'nrQuartos' , '>=' , $nrQuartos);      
   }
```

So i created another scope to search in Apartments table and its wrong

```
public function scopeProcuraNrQuartosApartamento($query,$nrQuartos){
    if ($nrQuartos != 0) $query ->join('apartamentos','imoveis.id', '=', 'apartamentos.imovel_id')
                                ->where( 'nrQuartos' , '>=' , $nrQuartos);      
   }
```

Controller

```
 $imo = Imovel::procuraFinalidade($finalidade)->procuraTipo($tipo)->procuraNrQuartosMoradia($nrQuartos)->procuraNrQuartosApartamento($nrQuartos)->paginate(9);
```

Is there any way to do this in a single scope like doing two joins to look at the table of houses and apartments?

For example, would UNION in this case work?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the **leftJoin** method twice, once for the **moradias** table (houses) and once for the **apartamentos** table (apartments). You can then use the **orWhere** method to combine the conditions. Here's how you can modify your scopes:

**Property model**

```
public function scopeProcuraNrQuartos($query, $nrQuartos)
{
    if ($nrQuartos != 0) {
        $query->leftJoin('moradias', 'imoveis.id', '=', 'moradias.imovel_id')
            ->where('nrQuartos', '>=', $nrQuartos)
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($nrQuartos) {
                $query->leftJoin('apartamentos', 'imoveis.id', '=', 'apartamentos.imovel_id')
                    ->where('nrQuartos', '>=', $nrQuartos);
            });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

in controller call this single scope:

```
$imo = Imovel::procuraFinalidade($finalidade)
    ->procuraTipo($tipo)
    ->procuraNrQuartos($nrQuartos)
    ->paginate(9);
```